# PHP Google Classroom API turnin() TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest

Tags: php, google-classroom

I'm trying to use the `turnIn()` function in the Google Classroom API for PHP.

On the PHP documentation, it says that it requires 4 parameters, the last of which is the `TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest`. I looked throughout the documentation and couldn't find any indication of what that is or where it is set.

On the main Google Classroom API documentation, it states that it requires the course ID, coursework ID, and submission ID, but I can't seem to figure out what the last parameter that is required in PHP is actually supposed to be. There's a page for it on the Google Classroom API PHP documentation but has no info on what it is or how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

It looks like you are using [Google's PHP client](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/php). If you inspect the body of the method:

```
/**
 * Turns in a student submission.
 *
 * Turning in a student submission transfers ownership of attached Drive files
 * to the teacher and may also update the submission state.
 *
 * This may only be called by the student that owns the specified student
 * submission.
 *
 * This request must be made by the Developer Console project of the [OAuth
 * client ID](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849) used to create
 * the corresponding course work item.
 *
 * This method returns the following error codes:
 *
 * * `PERMISSION_DENIED` if the requesting user is not permitted to access the
 * requested course or course work, turn in the requested student submission, or
 * for access errors. * `INVALID_ARGUMENT` if the request is malformed. *
 * `NOT_FOUND` if the requested course, course work, or student submission does
 * not exist. (studentSubmissions.turnIn)
 *
 * @param string $courseId Identifier of the course. This identifier can be
 * either the Classroom-assigned identifier or an alias.
 * @param string $courseWorkId Identifier of the course work.
 * @param string $id Identifier of the student submission.
 * @param Google_Service_Classroom_TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest $postBody
 * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
 * @return Google_Service_Classroom_ClassroomEmpty
 */
public function turnIn($courseId, $courseWorkId, $id, Google_Service_Classroom_TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest $postBody, $optParams = array())
{
  $params = array('courseId' => $courseId, 'courseWorkId' => $courseWorkId, 'id' => $id, 'postBody' => $postBody);
  $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
  return $this->call('turnIn', array($params), "Google_Service_Classroom_ClassroomEmpty");
}
```

You can see that the `Google_Service_Classroom_TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest` is extending `Google_Model`.

This is passed to the API call and looks like it is being used as the body of the post request:

```
// postBody is a special case since it's not defined in the discovery
// document as parameter, but we abuse the param entry for storing it.
$postBody = null;
if (isset($parameters['postBody'])) {
  if ($parameters['postBody'] instanceof Google_Model) {
    // In the cases the post body is an existing object, we want
    // to use the smart method to create a simple object for
    // for JSONification.
    $parameters['postBody'] = $parameters['postBody']->toSimpleObject();
  } else if (is_object($parameters['postBody'])) {
    // If the post body is another kind of object, we will try and
    // wrangle it into a sensible format.
    $parameters['postBody'] =
        $this->convertToArrayAndStripNulls($parameters['postBody']);
  }
  $postBody = (array) $parameters['postBody'];
  unset($parameters['postBody']);
}

// ...

$request = new Request(
    $method['httpMethod'],
    $url,
    ['content-type' => 'application/json'],
    $postBody ? json_encode($postBody) : ''
);
```

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/turnIn) the POST request body must be empty and PHP requires 4th parameter to be instance of `Google_Service_Classroom_TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest`.

Modify your calls like this:

```
$resource->turnIn(
    $courseId, 
    $courseWorkId, 
    $id, 
    new Google_Service_Classroom_TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest()
);
```

Comment: I did see that the documentation said that the post request body must be empty, but when I leave it out I get an error saying that it was expecting a 4th parameter.

Here's the error I get:
Argument 4 passed to Google_Service_Classroom_Resource_CoursesCourseWorkStudentSubmissions::turnIn() must be an instance of Google_Service_Classroom_TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest, none given

Comment: Updated the answer, you basically need to create an empty instance

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks, somehow missed that.